# cannot compare ostream and cout while compling visual studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

In header file
I have iostream include and decalred ostream object as below

```cpp
ostream &oustream;
```

In cpp file:

```
if(**oustream != cout**) // this line not working
```

```
error:binary '!=': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::ostream' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

This Programs works perfectly fine with vs2010 complier and has been issue with vs2017.

Comment: The standard `std::ostream` is not comparable. Your old compiler had that either as an extension or as a bug, but it is not portable. If you're desperate, you can compare the addresses, but if you're trying to determine whether the output is to a terminal, there is no standard way to do that.

Comment: Comparing addresses works same as before ? . Sample program did work  but concerned with fact that previously we were comparing identity and now we are comparing equality of objects.